# UITextView selectedRange returning incorrect value when using attributedText property

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a UITextView that is using an NSAttributedString via UITextView.attributedText.  When I call UITextView.selectedRange it gives incorrect values if the text contains special characters.  Anybody know how to get the correct selectedRange from a UITextView that has attributed text?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the selectedRange you're getting is incorrect? Note that some special characters such as emoji are represented by surrogate pairs and count as 2 characters.